# ASP.NET with jQuery DatePicker

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I would like to do something like this: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

However, I'm not exactly sure how:

1. I have a masterpage-content page, and when I tried to copy that code and paste them into the content page, it will say "XXXX cannot be in the content region".
2. When the user hit the submit button, how am I going to pass the date in the `textbox` to the server side code?

Here are parts of my code:

.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" runat="server">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

.cs:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = //The date from the datepicker
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `runat="server"` like this in your html:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server">
```

Then on your server side your can refer to `datepicker` as a server object and access `datepicker.Value`.

To @C.J comment. This is the source code included on [this link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) added on the question, it is there where the `runat=server` goes:

This goes on your **Master Page**:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

This goes on your **Content Page**:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"></p>
<script>
  $(document).on('ready',function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where do I include the `$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});` Because if I type them in the content page, it will return errors.

Comment: So, now you are copying my answer!! If you want i give you my vote up!! there is no problem!!

Comment: @Dalorzo I understand the code as per in the link. However, my question is, if I have a Master page, how am I going to call the function in the content page?

Comment: what function do you mean the javascript function?

Comment: I tried to include the codes `<!doctype html>` ... `<body>` in the content page, but it says these codes cannot be included in the content region

Comment: My bad, I should have explained the problem more clearly. So, basically in the `Masterpage`, you will have things like `ContentPlaceHolder`, then in the content page, it is where you enter all the contents. However, in the content page, I cannot/don't know how to include the `javascript` functions

Comment: @Dalorzo It doesn't work, the calender did not pop out in the content page

Comment: mmm try the updated answer if not I will need to know if your console is triggering any errors

Comment: @Dalorzo still not working. I am not picking up any error. I have also tried to inspect all the elements in the browser, doesn't look to me there should be any problem

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 use `type="date"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your datepicker and add `runat="server"` to your input like this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});


<input type="text" id="datepicker" runtat="server">
```