# jQuery DatePicker not working with Masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is a follow up question from [ASP.NET with jQuery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785806/asp-net-with-jquery-datepicker/23786022?noredirect=1#23786022)

I tried to use the jQuery UI DatePicker as suggested in this page: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-DatePicker-Calendar-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

When I tested the codes in a `SINGLE webform`, it works like a charm.

However, when I tried to incorporate them with `Masterpage` and `Contentpage`, I can't seem to make the calender working again.

This is what I have attempted so far:

In the `Masterpage`, I added the `script scr` and `link` in the `Head`:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<%--added below--%>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

Here is part of my codes in the `Contentpage`

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test2._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
```

What exactly have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

When you use master pages, each control that is specified with `runat="server"` will not actually have the ID you assign it. You can see the ID it has if you view the generated page source.

To get the actual ID, try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you're using UpdatePanels and you keep seeing your control getting unbound, replace `$(document).ready(function (){ ... });` with `function pageLoad() { ... }`.

Make sure the JavaScript is at the end of your content/body tag as well. This will ensure it gets loaded last after all the page controls.

So it should be something like

```
    // all my page content ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //sweet JS
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It DID pick up the ID now, but the calender is still not working (i.e. Can't see the calendar at all)

Comment: Nope... Still not working... I have tried both `$(document).ready(function (){ ... });` and `function pageLoad()`

Comment: Anything to do with ReadOnly="true" ?

Comment: Removing the ReadOnly="true" doesn't help either.

Comment: I figured out the cause, but do not know why. Please refer to this post for the follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790181/aspscriptmanager-what-is-that