# ASP:ScriptManager, what is that?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hope this is okay for posting a third follow up question. Original issues can be found here: [jQuery DatePicker not working with Masterpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788212/jquery-datepicker-not-working-with-masterpage/23788423?noredirect=1#comment36586473_23788423)

After a very long investigation, turns out there is nothing wrong with the JavaScript code at all. Instead, the problem occur when you created a new project in Visual Studio using the existing template, (I'm using 2013), in the Masterpage, you will find a bunch of codes as below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

When I deleted the entire codes above, all of my jQuery functions seem to be working again, "magically".

Now my questions are:

1. What is the ScriptManager for?
2. Why is it affecting my jQuery UI DatePicker?
3. If I remove those lines, how will it affect the project?
4. If yes, how do I resolve the issues?

Comment: Are you including jQuery twice?  The ScriptManager looks like it it already including jQuery for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Its responsible for bundling JavaScript files for your page(s) [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Could be many reasons, you'd have to check and see what error is being throwin in your js   debugger of choice.  All browsers have then now a days
3. Hard to tell, dont know anything about your project
4. See #3

Comment: It still doesn't explain why removing the ScriptManager will make the jQuery functions working again. Also, I have testing with the js debugger, there is not error being thrown

Answer (score 1):

script manager is a .net way of including and managing your script files. i would say they are not in the expected dir for the script manager to find them as the first 4 do not have a path to the files.

I would say to add the path to the first 4 in there and see if they are then able to find the files.

here are a couple of examples / tutorials for using script managers to give you a better idea 
[one simple ajax example](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/11/ajax-scriptmanager-how-to-use.html)

[the complicated extended explanation from asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx)